# Copy a text file and display it as it is

Tags: text, appendix, copy-paste

I have a log file from an analysis software which is in ".txt" form. Data is arranged in some useful order with symbols, matrices etc. in the file. I want to make the contents of it an appendix to my report. Is it possible to copy the entire text file after a short intro, say like this?

```
\chapter{Appendix}\label{chapter:Appendix}

\section{Appendix 1 : Sample log file - XXX Analysis}\label{xxx}
```

.......................... Here the file contents appear
..........................

Comment: `\verbatiminput{file.txt}` from the verbatim package for example

Comment: I am sorry I tried this, but nothing appears in my pdf. Would there be anything else I need to add to it or the remaining code?

Comment: you can't just get nothing, either the file should be printed or there will be warnings in the log file. Make a small test document that just does `\verbatiminput{file.txt}` and show the log

Comment: My mistake was that the entire path was not written. The file was contained in a folder. Thank you so much @DavidCarlisle for the help.

Comment: In this example, would it be possible to reduce (or specify) the size of the text in the verbatim part and/or shift the entire output say 1 cm, to the left?

Comment: `\small\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}\normalsize` would be smaller

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `\usepackage{verbatim}` (from the core LaTeX tools bundle) you can use

```
\verbatiminput{file.txt}
```

To input a file verbatim.